# Query SQL DB via asp.net only display row if column 3 is greater than or equal to column 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Okay I have been handed a project to code up an inventory tracker.  I'm doing it in asp.net mvc.  I have my sql db set up.  My question is exactly the title.  I have a page that works just fine that displays all the inventory items currently in the database. However I want the option to view a page that only displays items that are low in quantity.  my columns are as follows "ID, itemName, Quantity, statusLow, and updated last".  so essentially here is some psuedo code for what i'm looking for:

For each item in inventory
if (quantity <= statusLow)
{
   displayfor(item details)
}

Any help I could get would be amazing.

Comment: Take a look at the `WHERE` clause documentation/ samples.

Answer (score 1):

A simple `Where` clause should work for you

```
Select * 
from Yourtable 
Where quantity <= statusLow
```

Comment: But how do I execute this clause in c#?